# Unable to find client X509Certificate on server

Tags: asp.net

At Localhost below code is working fine but on server it can't able find client certificate.

```
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My,StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certificates = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
            store.Close();
            foreach (X509Certificate2 certificate in certificates)
            {

                    string SerialNumber = certificate.SerialNumber;
            }
        }
```

Comment: So, does the certificate exist on the server?

Comment: No,Certificate exist on at client end

Comment: "at client end" are you trying to get certificates on the client, the person using the browser?

Comment: I have a website that require user (digital signature) certificate to access some details and i am finding certificate SerialNumber to identifying it

Comment: But that doesn't really clarify the question. Where are you trying to find the certificate, from the server, or the person using the browser?

Comment: I am finding certificate of the client(person using browser) on server

Answer (score 0):

I bet you haven't placed the certificate in the app pool's identity store but rather, in a store of another user (yourself?).

Note that the search flag `CurrentUser` truly means current user, on a server the current user is the identity of the app pool.

Comment: Please tell me how can i get client certificate from his browser

Comment: Client certificate? You mean the user that uses your application? You can't actually.

Comment: Yes, Is there any way to get it

Comment: You can deploy a clickonce application from your web server. Such clickonce application is a normal desktop app that can access certificates without any restictions as it runs at the client side.

Comment: Please Explain more about clickonce application and the procedure

Answer (score 0):

You can't enumerate the certificates of the client - the person using the browser - using *server side* code. The reason it works with localhost is because the client and the server happen to be the same computer, so it appears to work. The code you are using is searching the certificate store on the server.

It's possible to configure IIS to ask the client to send certain kinds of certificates using Client Certificates, however this has certain limitations. Once you configure IIS to accept client certificates, you can access the certificate the client provided by looking at the [`ClientCertificate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.clientcertificate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the web request.

That all said, Client Certificates won't probably work the way you are expecting it to. The person using the browser *chooses* which certificate to send, you can't just start arbitrarily yanking certificates from the client.

Comment: Please provide the code so i can try or the way to enable IIS to accept client certificate

Comment: Please tell me how can i get client certificate from his browser